# Standards for two-finger touch gestures?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, touch-screen, cursor

I tried to define the follow gestures in a remote desktop app. (Native Touch vs. Cursor Mode) I am worried that the two finger behaviors are too difficult.

### One-finger (native touch)

1. One-finger tap = left-click
2. One-finger long-press = right-click
3. One-finger double-tap = double-click
4. One-finger tap & press = drag-and-drop

### Two-finger (cursor mode)

1. Two-finger pan moves mouse cursor around
2. Two-finger tap = click at cursor location
3. Two-finger long-press = right-click at cursor location
4. Two-finger double-tap = double-click at cursor location
5. Two-finger tap & press = drag-and-drop at cursor location

### The question

Which published standards can I use to assess whether this is a standard implementation, or to conduct a heuristic review?

Comment: On which platforms are you delivering this? iOS, Android, Windows, or all?

Comment: I think your first question is, what do you want to achieve with it - does it really need to be "hidden" by a gesture, as gestures are impossible to guess and depend entirely upon the previous experience one had with touch devices of a specific platform (as JeromeR correctly asks you to identify the platform as there are some "patterns" for each) and also requires cognitive load to remember which ones work where - So, if possible, try to omit them alltogether and try to see if there are things that provide these invisible actions by other means. Or if not, provide instant feedback on interact.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for resources to review and compare against, I would suggest looking at most popular devices in the market today. Below is the list I was able to find:

1. [Windows Touch Gestures Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [New gestures you have to master to tame Windows 10](http://bgr.com/2015/03/19/windows-10-new-gestures/)
3. [Use Multi-Touch gestures on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895)
4. [Google Design Patterns - Touch](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/gestures.html#)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an illustration of various gestures—but not necessarily what these gestures do. Does this help you to search/research/ask questions?

I just found this illustration as the answer to a different question.

[image: Stencil of touch gestures]